# IE jQuery ajax results in a stack overflow

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I have the following code that in IE gives me an error in jQuery for "open(G,M.url,M.async"

```
$("#submitButton").click(function(){            
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://url.com/postChat.php",
        data: "comment="+$("#userInput").val(),
        success: function(msg){

        }
    });             
});
```

Any ideas as to why this would happen in IE?

Comment: is your success function actually blank in your test? If not, could that be causing the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `return false;` at the end of your click handler.

Answer (score 0):

Is this code run multiple times? If you were to bind 5000 click handlers to the same element, you'd see the stack overflow for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't that be:

```
$("#submitButton").click(function(){            
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://url.com/postChat.php",
        data: { 'comment': $("#userInput").val() },
        success: function(msg){

        }
    });             
});
```

Comment: Ends up the same since jQuery will serialize 1-deep objects and turn it into a query string. In other words: `{a: 1} == "a=1"`, but more importantly: `{a: 1, b: 2} == "a=1&b=2" -- I agree that the syntax presented here is cleaner and more maintainable, but it wont affect the error he's getting here.